# how to write cascade query in mysql using references

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query. But it is not working.
It show this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 23

query:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_student 
  ( 
     studentrollno     INT(11), 
     studentname       VARCHAR(255), 
     studentpassword   VARCHAR(255), 
     studentslug       VARCHAR(300), 
     studentstatus     VARCHAR(255), 
     degreetitle       VARCHAR(100), 
     batchtitle        VARCHAR(100), 
     batchautomationno VARCHAR(100), 
     PRIMARY KEY (studentrollno), 
     FOREIGN KEY (degreetitle) REFERENCES tbl_batch(degreetitle) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
     FOREIGN KEY (batchtitle) REFERENCES tbl_batch(batchtitle) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
     FOREIGN KEY (batchautomationno) REFERENCES tbl_batch(batchautomationno)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  )
```

This is my batch table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_batch (
  degreeTitle varchar(100),
  batchTitle varchar(100),
  batchAutomationNo varchar(100),
  batchSlug varchar(255),
  batchStatus int(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (degreeTitle, batchTitle, batchAutomationNo),
  FOREIGN KEY (degreeTitle)
  REFERENCES tbl_degree(degreeTitle)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Remove last comma

Comment: If I remove last comma,
this error comes
#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: This is real error *Cannot add foreign key constraint* and you need to update your question with table definitions which you are referencing

Comment: How to solve this real error?

Comment: Update your question with all table definitions

Comment: This is all about my table.

Comment: Nope. We need `tbl_batch` definition.

Comment: Okay, obviously your situation is unique, your error has never been encountered, it's clearly a bug in every piece of software and nothing you are doing wrong. So I guess that would mean it can't be done and you should probably stop trying.

Comment: I bet you $5 that this one of the foreign keys is type `TEXT` : "Index prefixes on foreign key columns are not supported. One consequence of this is that BLOB and TEXT columns cannot be included in a foreign key because indexes on those columns must always include a prefix length."

Comment: In batch table..
batchTitle, degreeTitle, batchAutomationNo are primary keys.

Comment: you have 3 foreign keys pointing to the same table and that table has 3 primary keys? I'm not a DBA, but isn't that pointless and, i dunno, likely not allowed?

Comment: If the parent has a composite primary key, then child can have composite foreign key. But I would have defined a foreign key mapping to the auto incremented pk value of parent composite *unique* key.

Comment: I have update my question with batch table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *In batch table.. batchTitle, degreeTitle, batchAutomationNo are primary keys.*

You can have a composite foreign key mapped to parent composite primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_student 
( 
    studentrollno     INT(11), 
    studentname       VARCHAR(255), 
    studentpassword   VARCHAR(255), 
    studentslug       VARCHAR(300), 
    studentstatus     VARCHAR(255), 
    degreetitle       VARCHAR(100), 
    batchtitle        VARCHAR(100), 
    batchautomationno VARCHAR(100), 
    PRIMARY KEY (studentrollno), 
    FOREIGN KEY (degreeTitle, batchTitle, batchAutomationNo) 
      REFERENCES tbl_batch(degreeTitle, batchTitle, batchAutomationNo) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Always note that to define individual FK's you should also have individual parent keys.